# using matrix for scale of normal distribution

Tags: python

I'm having trouble making synthetic data for some clustering tasks.

I want to create 200 data vectors x of 20 dimensions.

For generating them, I first prepared centers of clusters `m` of 5 dimensions and a linear transformation `A` of (20, 5) shapes, where all the elements are generated from N(0,1) independently.

Then data vectors are genereted by `x_i ~ N(Am_k, I)`, where `I` is an identity matrix of (20, 20) shape.

here is the code I wrote,

```
import numpy as np
A = np.random.normal(0, 1, (20, 5))
m1 = np.random.normal(0, 1, (5,))  # center of clusters
for _ in range(50):
    data1.append(np.random.normal(np.matmul(A, m1), np.identity(20)))
x1 = np.vstack(data1) # x1.shape -> (1000, 20)
```

in this code, I tried to generate 50 data vectors from center of the cluster `m1`.

The shape of `x1` should be `(50,20)`, but the output shape is `(1000, 20)`.

So I changed the value of scale from `np.identity(20)` to `1` and got the data with the shape of `(50, 20)` .

But I'm not sure if such changes guarantee the reproducibility of the data vectors.

The questions are, do `np.random.normal(np.matmul(A, m1), np.identity(20))` and `np.random.normal(np.matmul(A, m1), 1)` produce the same data?
And how should I inplement `x_i ~ N(Am_k, I)`?

edit: number of classes are k=4, and the class of x_i is assigned from 1 to 4 for every 50 data vectors.

Comment: If you want to repeatable results between runs you could seed a new generator: https://towardsdatascience.com/stop-using-numpy-random-seed-581a9972805f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> in this code, I tried to generate 50 data vectors from center of the cluster m1.
> The shape of x1 should be (50,20), but the output shape is (1000, 20).

So the problem here is that you're using [`np.random.normal`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.normal.html) instead of [`np.random.multivariate_normal`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.multivariate_normal.html#numpy-random-multivariate-normal), so you should really have

```py
for _ in range(50):
    data1.append(np.random.multivariate_normal(np.matmul(A, m1), np.identity(20)))
```

> The questions are, do np.random.normal(np.matmul(A, m1), np.identity(20)) and np.random.normal(np.matmul(A, m1), 1) produce the same data? And how should I inplement x_i ~ N(Am_i, I)?

No, they wouldn't produce the same data. The shapes they output aren't the same, so they won't produce the same data. The first one generates something weird where the i-th column changes for the i-th row where it's by default `Am_i @ I`, the second one generates what you want, it'll draw each coordinate with variance one independent of the other dimensions. But if you want to explicitly drawn from a multivariate Gaussian in the future, then you can get `x_i~N(Am_i,I)` by using `np.random.multivariate_normal`.